# mongodb sorting group result

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the first of each group, then I need to sort the resultset. I have achieved the first part but unable to sort the result. Here is what I have tried

Sample Data

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f549e1831529409b000001"),"name" : "book1","author" : "abc","revision" : 1.0,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:43:45.902Z"),"publisher" : "newpublisher"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f54a4483152940ad000001"),"name" : "book1","author" : "a1","revision" : 1.1,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:45:24.436Z"), "publisher" : "newpublisher"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f54baa83152940c3000001"), "name" : "oldbook", "author" : "alice","revision" : 1.0,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:51:22.484Z"),"publisher" : "newpublisher"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f54c4983152940c3000002"),"name" : "artoflearning","author" : "mike","revision" : 1.0,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:54:01.585Z"),"publisher" : "oldpublisher"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f54c5883152940c3000003"),"name" : "artoflearning","author" : "mike","revision" : 1.1,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:54:16.568Z"),"publisher" : "oldpublisher"
},
{   "_id" : ObjectId("57f54c6583152940c3000004"),"name" : "artoflearning","author" : "mike","revision" : 1.2,
    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T18:54:29.848Z"),"publisher" : "oldpublisher"
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f5513f8315294116000000"),"name" : "learning","author" : "mike","revision" : 2.0,
  "published_on" : ISODate("2016-10-05T19:15:11.342Z"),"publisher" : "newpublisher"
}
```

I am getting latest revision (sort by revision in desc) group by name for a given publisher. I have used this query to achieve

```
Book.collection.aggregate([
{'$match' =>  {"publisher"=>"newpublisher"}},
{'$sort' => {'revision' => -1}},
{'$group' => {'_id' => '$name', 
            'revision' => {'$first' => '$revision'}, 
            'id' => {'$first' => '$_id'},
            'name' => {'$first' => '$name'},
            'published_on' => {'$first' => '$published_on'},
            'publisher' => {'$first' => '$publisher'}
            }
},
{'$project' => {'_id' => '$id', 
                'revision' => '$revision', 
                'name' => '$name',
                'published_on' => '$published_on',
                'publisher' => '$publisher'
              }
},
{'$skip' => 1},
{ '$limit' => 10 }
])
```

Since I need paginated result, I have applied skip and limit.
I have got this result

```
{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"57f54a4483152940ad000001"}, "revision"=>1.1, "name"=>"book1", "published_on"=>"2016-10-05T18:45:24.436Z", "publisher"=>"newpublisher"}, 
{"_id"=>{"$oid"=>"57f5513f8315294116000000"}, "revision"=>2.0, "name"=>"learning", "published_on"=>"2016-10-05T19:15:11.342Z", "publisher"=>"newpublisher"}
```

Now I would like to sort by 'name' or 'published_on' columns. When I try to apply that on the result from above, I am getting error

Please advise

Comment: does appending a `{'$sort' => {'name' => 1}}` at the end of your pipeline not work?

Comment: @Rafael, yes that worked. How do I get the total count of the grouped result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't said what error you're getting, that would help. But you said

> Now I would like to sort by 'name' or 'published_on' columns. When I try to apply that on the result from above, I am getting error

and by that I understand you added the `sort` after the `limit`. If you did that, it only sorts the skipped and limited results, in order to sort all results you must call the sort before skipping and limiting them, like:

```
Book.collection.aggregate([
  {'$match' =>  {"publisher"=>"newpublisher"}},
  {'$sort' => {'revision' => -1}},
  {'$group' => {'_id' => '$name', 
              'revision' => {'$first' => '$revision'}, 
              'id' => {'$first' => '$_id'},
              'name' => {'$first' => '$name'},
              'published_on' => {'$first' => '$published_on'},
              'publisher' => {'$first' => '$publisher'}
              }
  },
  {'$project' => {'_id' => '$id', 
                  'revision' => '$revision', 
                  'name' => '$name',
                  'published_on' => '$published_on',
                  'publisher' => '$publisher'
                }
  },
  {'$sort' => {'name' => 1}},
  {'$skip' => 1},
  {'$limit' => 10 }
])
```

I added the documents you posted in a collection and ran this query and this is the result

```
[ { _id: 57f5513f8315294116000000,
    revision: 2,
    name: 'learning',
    published_on: Wed Oct 05 2016 16:15:11 GMT-0300 (BRT),
    publisher: 'newpublisher' },
  { _id: 57f54baa83152940c3000001,
    revision: 1,
    name: 'oldbook',
    published_on: Wed Oct 05 2016 15:51:22 GMT-0300 (BRT),
    publisher: 'newpublisher' } ]
```

And sorted by `published_on`:

`{'$sort': {'published_on': 1}}`

```
[ { _id: 57f54baa83152940c3000001,
    revision: 1,
    name: 'oldbook',
    published_on: Wed Oct 05 2016 15:51:22 GMT-0300 (BRT),
    publisher: 'newpublisher' },
  { _id: 57f5513f8315294116000000,
    revision: 2,
    name: 'learning',
    published_on: Wed Oct 05 2016 16:15:11 GMT-0300 (BRT),
    publisher: 'newpublisher' } ]
```

Comment: How do I get the total count of the grouped result to be shown along with the output

Comment: Add this to the group object:
`'count' => {'$sum' => 1}`

Comment: that would give me individual count per name, so for the above result, I am getting count: 1 for each record, but I need total count : 2

Comment: Do you want the count of the final result? The aggregate returns an array, so you can easily use `results.length`. But if you want it to return an object like `{ 'books': [<your_results>], 'count': 2}` then you'll need more stages in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: yes, in other words, 'total_count' => {'$sum' => '$count'} something like this, which I would return {'books': [result], total_count: 3}, even the result is only 2 if we skip 1 for example